# Alternatives to a hard reset when screen is frozen on Android Froyo?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-one, system-freeze

My Nexus One has been freezing up a lot lately, particularly in Settings. Are there any good alternatives to pulling the battery when this happens?

Comment: As mentioned below, try nailing down what process(es) cause the freeze(s).

Comment: [Watchdog Task Manager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/watchdog-task-manager/com.zomut.watchdog) (and the [Light](http://www.appbrain.com/app/watchdog-task-manager-lite/com.zomut.watchdoglite) edition) is good at highlighting apps which peg the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

This may not apply to the Nexus One but when this happens to me on my droid I turn the screen off wait a couple seconds and turn it back on. Sometimes it comes back fine other times it comes back with an option to force close the hanging program. Either way I never have to pull the battery just force close the process.

Comment: Yeah, I can't turn the screen off at all when this happens. Sometimes the option to force-close pops up, which usually solves the problem.

Comment: Wow, turning the screen off is one thing that always works for me. I wish I had some more advice for you. What process is hanging when you do get the force close option?

Comment: I've gotten the force close option when I was switching wireless networks. Even then, sometimes it takes on the order of a minute or so to get the force close option. As for totally locked up, Angry Birds is one app that has done that a couple of times to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the home button, on unrooted devices, the Home button can only be overriden by Home Screen apps so unless your Home Screen is freezing as well, it usually can bring you back to the home screen so you can force close the freezing app from the application manager (Settings > Manage applications > "app name" > Force stop).

Comment: None of the 4 buttons shows any response that I can elicit when this happens, unless there's some combination or holding of a button for a period of time that can interrupt the freeze.